# 1 URL --> 2 results : 1 before a certain hour, 2 after

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking for some pages like this:

> Referer : "http://cheval-francais.eu/fr/resultats-officiels.html"
>
> Menu    : "http://cheval-francais.eu/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=21&Itemid=45"
>
> Results (XML) : "http://cheval-francais.eu/courses/result_officiel_ficheliste3_fic.php?date=20110213&&societe=4901&&course=01&&groupe="

Results on the page change after the time of the events.

> 1- partants : "etatPeriode = PAR"
>
> 2- arrivants: "etatPeriode = RES" or "REP".

Is there a way to block "time" or change something with vba code to get just the results
of the first state (before time event) or all results on 2-arrivants (without blanked data)?

For `arrivants`, the XML Result is on the same schema, with all fields of `partants`
but data are blank. I would like to get data from the past for `partants` (like `<defere>`, `<ordre>` and some others.

I use VBA, and just call the XML page "results".

Comment: Could you give more detail of what these pages need to be? Is it excel or html?  When do these results change exactly? Please explain it more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to download XML data from a website over which you have no control, but you want to download the data as it was shown at an earlier date/time.
If so, I think the only possiblity would be if you can add some parameter to the URL to specify what you want to download.

So for example, if you currently download from the URL:

```
http://cheval-francais.eu/courses/result_officiel_ficheliste3_fic.php?date=20110213&&societe=4901&&course=01&&groupe=
```

Then maybe you could instead change this to:

```
http://cheval-francais.eu/courses/result_officiel_ficheliste3_fic.php?date=20110213&&etatPeriode=PAR&&societe=4901&&course=01&&groupe=
```

But it would be up to the website code if it handles the `etatPeriode` parameter or not. Otherwise I can't see how you could get access to historical data. Though if you only need access to the historical data in the future and you don't need access to older data than "now", I suppose you could just create your code to download the data from the website every day before the specified time and store it locally in some way (assuming that this is allowed according to any licenses for usage of the data etc).